# How to upload an image to a div based input | Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Thanks for looking after my question.
I'm trying to create a simple Python script to upload images to my group.

Facebook doesn't use the  tag for image uplaod, instead it looks like so:

```
<div aria-label="Write something..." class="notranslate _5rpu" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" style="outline: currentcolor none medium; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; overflow-wrap: break-word;" tabindex="0" aria-describedby="placeholder-c0e70" contenteditable="true">...</div>
```

I managed to post text through it, but it didn't work with images. I tried this and still it doesn't work:

```
write_post_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-label='Write something...']")))
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(write_post_input).click().perform()
        write_post_input.clear()
        write_post_input.send_keys(image_path)
```

It only uploads the path of the image not the image itself.
I want to mention that this might look different on Firefox. I'm using Chrome.

By the way, I know about the Facebook API, I'm just curious about this specific task.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has to be :

```
<input>
```

So you can't solve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).